# Negative bar chart values not working with react-chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have been trying for days to get negative values to work correctly when using react-chartjs. I know that Chart.js itself supports this so clearly there is an issue in the React.js implementation.

Any thoughts anyone might have on this would be greatly appreciated. Below is how the charts are outputting right now.

[image]

Comment: Can you share with us how you initialized your BarChart component ?

Comment: reactjs depends on chart.js. Which version of chart.js are you using? This is huge. Chart.js got out of Beta two weeks ago and they've already had 3 revs. You might be better off declaring an explicit dependency on a v1 version of chart.js.